# Pandas: aggregate when column contains numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, aggregation

I'm using a pandas DataFrame in which one column contains numpy arrays.  When trying to sum that column via aggregation I get an error stating 'Must produce aggregated value'.

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

DF = pd.DataFrame([[1,np.array([10,20,30])],
               [1,np.array([40,50,60])], 
               [2,np.array([20,30,40])],], columns=['category','arraydata'])
```

This works the way I would expect it to:

```
DF.groupby('category').agg(sum)
```

output:

```
             arraydata
category 1   [50 70 90]
         2   [20 30 40]
```

However, since my real data frame has multiple numeric columns, arraydata is not chosen as the default column to aggregate on, and I have to select it manually.  Here is one approach I tried:

```
g=DF.groupby('category')
g.agg({'arraydata':sum})
```

Here is another:

```
g=DF.groupby('category')
g['arraydata'].agg(sum)
```

Both give the same output:

```
Exception: must produce aggregated value
```

However if I have a column that uses numeric rather than array data, it works fine.  I can work around this, but it's confusing and I'm wondering if this is a bug, or if I'm doing something wrong.  I feel like the use of arrays here might be a bit of an edge case and indeed wasn't sure if they were supported.  Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: On a stylistic note, all-uppercase variable names usually indicate "constant" variables (and capitalized/camelcase names tend to be reserved for classes). Using pythonic style will make it easier for other people to read your code - [PEP8 has guidelines on this](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Please note this just works as of 2017.

Comment: @Ieezu can it be that it stopped working again as of 2021?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One, perhaps more clunky way to do it would be to iterate over the `GroupBy` object (it generates `(grouping_value, df_subgroup)` tuples.  For example, to achieve what you want here, you could do:

```
grouped = DF.groupby("category")
aggregate = list((k, v["arraydata"].sum()) for k, v in grouped)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(aggregate, columns=["category", "arraydata"]).set_index("category")
```

This is very similar to what pandas is doing under the hood anyways [groupby, then do some aggregation, then merge back in], so you aren't really losing out on much.

---

#### Diving into the Internals

The problem here is that pandas is checking explicitly that the output *not* be an `ndarray` because it wants to intelligently reshape your array, as you can see in this snippet from `_aggregate_named` where the error occurs.

```
def _aggregate_named(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    result = {}

    for name, group in self:
        group.name = name
        output = func(group, *args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(output, np.ndarray):
            raise Exception('Must produce aggregated value')
        result[name] = self._try_cast(output, group)

    return result
```

My guess is that this happens because `groupby` is explicitly set up to try to intelligently put back together a DataFrame with the same indexes and everything aligned nicely. Since it's rare to have nested arrays in a DataFrame like that, it checks for ndarrays to make sure that you are actually using an aggregate function. In my gut, this feels like a job for `Panel`, but I'm not sure how to transform it perfectly.  As an aside, you can sidestep this problem by converting your output to a list, like this:

```
DF.groupby("category").agg({"arraydata": lambda x: list(x.sum())})
```

Pandas doesn't complain, because now you have an array of Python objects. [but this is really just cheating around the typecheck]. And if you want to convert back to array, just apply `np.array` to it.

```
result = DF.groupby("category").agg({"arraydata": lambda x: list(x.sum())})
result["arraydata"] = result["arraydata"].apply(np.array)
```

How you want to resolve this issue really depends on *why* you have columns of `ndarray` and whether you want to aggregate anything else at the same time. That said, you can always iterate over `GroupBy` like I've shown above.

Comment: Interesting.  Stuffing an array into the dataframe was a quick fix that is turning out to be more trouble than it's worth, so I think I will find another way.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas works much more efficiently if you *don't* do this (e.g using numeric data, as you suggest). Another alternative is to use a [Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel) object for this kind of multidimensional data.

Saying that, this looks like a bug, the Exception is being raised purely because the result is an array:

```
Exception: Must produce aggregated value

In [11]: %debug
> /Users/234BroadWalk/pandas/pandas/core/groupby.py(1511)_aggregate_named()
   1510             if isinstance(output, np.ndarray):
-> 1511                 raise Exception('Must produce aggregated value')
   1512             result[name] = self._try_cast(output, group)

ipdb> output
array([50, 70, 90])
```

If you were to recklessly remove these two lines from the source code it works as expected:

```
In [99]: g.agg(sum)
Out[99]:
             arraydata
category
1         [50, 70, 90]
2         [20, 30, 40]
```

*Note: They're almost certainly in there for a reason...*

Comment: Sidenote: to make a Panel object, you'd need to broadcast category to be 2d as well. So each input would need to be `[1,1,1], [20,30,40]`, etc. I have 0 experience with Panel, so I couldn't comment.

Comment: Interestingly the only failed tests I get are for the exception not being raised... and the examples "work".

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely not sure about that. It may just be that they want to preserve the separation of concerns between `groupby` and `transform`? Or perhaps it's a check that the aggregation is happening how you'd expect? (i.e., for groupby to work the way you want, it needs to return a "scalar-ish" value)

Answer (score 0):

Since the sum function only iterate over rows, or sum function only calculates the sum along the first axis.
You can define an aggregation function:

```
def mySum(dataframe):

    return np.sum(np.sum(dataframe))
```

And then pass this function into the `agg()`:

```
DF.groupby('category').agg(mySum)
```