# Pandas Function does not reduce

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I try to aggregate column contains numpy arrays
unfortunately, I have a error message **Function does not reduce**

```
results = pd.DataFrame([['p1', 'v1', 1, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v1', 2, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v1', 1, 1 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v1', 2, 1 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v2', 1, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v2', 2, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v2', 2, 1 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v2', 1, 1 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v3', 1, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v3', 2, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v3', 3, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v3', 4, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v4', 1, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v4', 2, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v4', 3, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v4', 4, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])]],columns=['P', 'V', 'G', 'month', 'Values'])
resultsilter = results.query('V=="v1" or V=="v2"')
resultsilter = resultsilter.groupby(['G','month']).agg({'Values': 'sum'})
print(resultsilter)
```

I would like to get this results like:

```
[[1, 0 ,np.array(2,6,8])],[2, 0 ,np.array([2,6,8])],[1, 1 ,np.array([2,6,8])],[2, 1 ,np.array([2,6,8])]]
```

any ideas?

Comment: What versions of pandas and numpy are you using?

Comment: version pandas : 0.25.1

Comment: version numpy : 1.16.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: aggregate when column contains numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975318/pandas-aggregate-when-column-contains-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

So I read up on the query() method and there is an alternative method. This is what I did:

```css
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

results = pd.DataFrame([['p1', 'v1', 1, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v1', 2, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v1', 1, 1 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v1', 2, 1 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v2', 1, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v2', 2, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v2', 2, 1 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v2', 1, 1 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v3', 1, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v3', 2, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v3', 3, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v3', 4, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v4', 1, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v4', 2, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])],['p1', 'v4', 3, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])], ['p1', 'v4', 4, 0 ,np.array([1,3, 4])]], columns=['P', 'V', 'G', 'month', 'Values'])
resultsilter = results[(results["V"] == "v1") | (results["V"] == "v2")] #this is the equivalent of  query('V=="v1" or V=="v2"')
resultsilter = resultsilter.groupby(['G','month']).agg({'Values': 'sum'})
resultsilter.reset_index(inplace=True)#fixes format after groupby().agg() is used
print(resultsilter.head())
```